# Submit all forms using Ajax with 1 button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a dynamic amount of forms by pressing one button. The form has seperate submit buttons and updating the data works with that button.

I made a fixed button on the bottom of the page that I would like to be able to submit all forms. So you can adjust all the data in all the forms, press 1 button and update all the data in the database.

Like I said, the updating the database part works (for a single form).

So this is my current code:

```
<button id="saveall" style="position: fixed; bottom: 20px;">Opslaan</button>
<script>
$( "#saveall" ).click(function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    $("form.edit_form").each(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data); // show response from the php script.
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This is what a form looks like:

```
<form class="edit_form" method="post" action="/collectie-manager-edit">
            <input type="hidden" name="UID" value="%UID%">
            <div>
                <label>Titel</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="titel" value="%titel%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Merk</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="merk" value="%merk%">
            </div>
             <div>
                <label>Prijs</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="prijs" value="%prijs%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Jurkcode</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="jurkcode" value="%jurkcode%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Jurk Titel</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="Jurktitel" value="%Jurktitel%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Youtube code</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="youtubecode" value="%youtubecode%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Custom url</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="custom_url" value="%custom_url%">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Positie</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="positie" value="%positie%">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="change_item" value="opslaan">
        </form>
```

Current php code handeling the form submit (single):

```
if(isset($_POST['change_item'])){
        $result = $db->update(
            "collectie",
            ["UID" => $_POST['UID']],               // get
            ["titel" => $_POST['titel'],"merk" => $_POST['merk'],"prijs" => $_POST['prijs'],"jurkcode" => $_POST['jurkcode'],"Jurktitel" => $_POST['Jurktitel'],"youtubecode" => $_POST['youtubecode'],"custom_url" => $_POST['custom_url'], "positie" => $_POST['positie']]                            // getFuzzy
        );
    }
```

What happends currently?

It spits out all the html into the console and nothing happends in the .php
The form handler is in the same php controller as the page. So the action points to the same page.

I have never used Ajax and I think its extremely confusing.

I can't find anything on the web that says I need different php for handling the ajax method. And seeing that I get 0 errors I am unsure of what to do to fix it.

ps: All the values that has %% in them are filled by the cms the page is build with. They are filled with values from the database.

**Edit on why this question is different from the one that is linked.**

That question asks how to dynamically post inputs not seperate forms. I have tried the answers in that question and they do not work.

A quote from the question:

I have a form with name orderproductForm and an **undefined number of inputs**.

I want to do some kind of jQuery.get or ajax or anything like that that would call a page through Ajax, and **send along all the inputs of the form** orderproductForm.

Comment: Can you share us your PHP code?

Comment: @iArcadia I have added the php, but I doubt it will be much use to you. Its a method from the cms. But its basically a simple update to the database.

Comment: can there be forms that contain elements of the same names?

Comment: What does your PHP return? It seems there is no problem in what you show.

Comment: @RamRaider All the forms have the exact same layout. So exact same input names etc.

Comment: @iArcadia It does not return anything. This php code directly updates the correct row with the data from the form. That works fine tho. It updates correctly.

Comment: @iArcadia Well let me rephrase that. it does output something: 1. So not much use :)

Comment: It updates correctly? Just for one form submit or it also works for your button which does your multi-ajax submitting? Yep, the returned value will not help us!

Comment: @iArcadia It works fine for a single submit (not with ajax method). So when I press the input submit of a form. Not the submit all button.

Comment: your code seems to be working see https://jsbin.com/nuwuyevede/edit?html,js,console,output click run with js before you click the button.

Comment: @julekgwa It may be correct frontend but backend it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get it.

Use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Example result with `.serialize()`:

```
UID=5&titel=myTitel
```

Example result with `.serializeArray()`:

```
[
    { name: 'UID', value: '5' },
    { name: 'titel', value: 'myTitel' }
]
```

Also, check if your submit button (`change_item`) is in your array, if that's not the case (and will not because that's an input button), you may add it in your serialized array, or update your PHP controller.

Be aware that with `.serializeArray()`, you will not be able to retrieve your input data with `$_POST['input_name']`, as indexes are integer (from 0 to your array length). Here's a function to convert your array:

```
let serialized = [
    {name: 'UID', value: '5'},
    {name: 'titel', value: 'myTitle'}
];

serialized = formatSerializedFormForAjax(serialized);

function formatSerializedFormForAjax(serialized) {
    let result = {};

    for (let i in serialized) {
        result[serialized[i].name] = serialized[i].value;
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(serialized);
```

If you use if in your code:

```
// form and url
let data = formatSerializedFormForAjax(form.serializedArray());

$.ajax({
   // ...
   data: data,
   // ...
});
```

Now you should be able to get your input values with `$_POST['UID']`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code I have above with your change just logs me the whole html of the page instead of just an array. So not sure if the intitial code is correct.

Comment: What if you log `form.serialize()` and the `url` variable before sending the AJAX?

Comment: That seemed to work and no change_item is not in the array.

Comment: Can you give us the content of the `console.log()`? If `change_item` is not in your array, so `isset($_POST['change_item'])` will never be `true`. ;) You may have to add it manually before sending your request.

Comment: But even if I for example add a die(); when $_POST['UID'] isset. It still does not get triggered when I use the ajax submit. Even when  it logs Success! for all 16 forms that are on the page

Comment: The contents of an array example: 
0: {name: "UID", value: "1234"}
1: {name: "titel", value: "This is a title"}
2: {name: "merk", value: "Brand"}
3: {name: "prijs", value: "1249"}
4: {name: "jurkcode", value: "Set 405"}
5: {name: "Jurktitel", value: "jurktitel"}
6: {name: "youtubecode", value: ""}
7: {name: "custom_url", value: "custom-url-page"}
8: {name: "positie", value: "1234"}

Comment: "But even if I for example add a die(); when $_POST['UID'] isset. It still does not get triggered when I use the ajax submit."

I am not sure to really understand that point. In your current PHP, your database will update if `isset($_POST['change_item'])` is `true`. As it is not the case, `$db->update()` will not be executed. But the fact that your AJAX executes your `success` callback is not linked, that's just because there is actually no error.

Comment: What I meant is, that if I add: if(isset($_POST['UID'])){
        die($_POST['UID']);
    } to the php controller (outside of the if isset($_POST['change_item']) and it still does not die when I press the save all button. It may not have the change_item post data but it should have the UID that is in the form. But its almost like the ajax does not even reach the php file.

Comment: Because `$_POST['UID']` does not exist. But `$_POST[0]` does. (with `$POST[0]['name']` is equal to `UID`).

Comment: I didnt think of that. But it still does not die when I filter on that. I am now starting to think, either the cms is blocking something or the ajax is not pointing to the right location.

Comment: I edited my post with a possible solution. Tell me if it works

Comment: I edited it in. It puts out 16 success's but still unable to catch anything in my php file.

Comment: I updated my `formatSerializedFormForAjax` function, it initialized `result` as an array instead of an object. I tried in a local test project (simple html form with ajax, and a `var_dump($_POST)` in my PHP, and I can access my data.)

Comment: I am honestly at a loss. I have the exact same code, the ajax gives me a succes every single time and no matter where I send the damn ajax call nothing happends. NO error or anything.

Comment: Weiiiird... Can you give me the content of `var_dump($_POST)` placed at the right start of your `collectie-manager-edit` controller method?

Comment: Its all the data that is needed to generate the results of the page. There is nothing in there from the ajax post tho.

Comment: I have not any solution left right now... What is the CMS you are using?

Comment: Its a custom PHP CMS. I guess there is no way  for me to use ajax. The cms will not allow it. :(

Comment: Is there any way to ask the developer(s) about that?

Comment: The cms was created some time ago by programmers who do not work here anymore. So that is not possible. I guess ill have to find a different way. Thanks for your effort tho :)

Comment: No problem. You could search in the source code and may find some hints. ;)